# Add days to PHP date taken from a variable - strange behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, date, variables

I've got this issue: I have to add some days to a date taken from a variable that contains a date value from an array.
I've followed many guides found here but it gives me a strange behaviour. When I export the .csv file that results from all the code processing, we can realize that the date is processed incorrectly and despite I use the correct PHP commands it seems that adds the wanted number to the months, not to the days resulting in an incorrect result of the .csv.  How can it be?

I'm going to paste the code below:

```
// === data

            $newDateAdd = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($readyForExport['date_add']));
            $readyForExport['date_add'] = $newDateAdd;


            // aggiungo 21 giorni - 3 settimane - alla data di acquisto
            $date_mod = date_create($newDateAdd);
            date_add($date_mod,date_interval_create_from_date_string("2 days"));
            $readyForExport['delivery_date'] = date_format($date_mod,"d/m/Y");
```

I also upload a screenshot where we can see that in the .csv are added the months not the days...

[csv screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDsVn.png)

many thanks.

Comment: Don't mix using `strtotime()` and `DateTime()`. Just use  `DateTime()` and its related classes for all date manipulation and calculations.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You need to add an example using real values showing what results you expect and what results you get.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot to be the most clear as possible, the 6th column must contain the result of the dates in the 5th column plus some days ( in example 21 days). https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDsVn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the DateTime object for this.
First it is object oriented which is preferred.
Also to my knowledge it has more refined code for manipulation.

```
$newDateAdd = new DateTime($readyForExport['date_add']);
$readyForExport['date_add'] = $newDateAdd->format('d/m/Y');


// aggiungo 21 giorni - 3 settimane - alla data di acquisto
$date_mod = clone $newDateAdd;
$date_mod->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
$readyForExport['delivery_date'] = $date_mod->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Well, `date_create` IS the DateTime constructor according to php documentation.

Comment: @Adder well that is why IMHO the functions should not be used at all and implementing them was a mistake in the first place. One can not directly recognize that you are working with an object and not with a string or a timestamp

Comment: Thanks to every one for the help, I've tried all the solutions but the one who worked for me is the one above in Object Oriented Programming style. I think it's the most clear and reliable solution.

Comment: @DarioFilidei Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as the accepted answer then, so others can see that the problem is solved and which answer solved the issue

Comment: @DarioFilidei keep in mind that if `$readyForExport['date_add']` is not a valid date, an exception will be thrown, or if it is `NULL` it will use the current date (equivalent of using `now`). I suggest utilizing `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $readyForExport['date_add'])` for the specific format the date value will use, and validate the return is not false see [PHP Manual Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that DateTime constructor expects the data as m/d/Y.

It is better to use the result of strtotime directly:

```
    $utime = strtotime($readyForExport['date_add']);
    $newDateAdd = date("d/m/Y", $utime);
    $readyForExport['date_add'] = $newDateAdd;


    // aggiungo 21 giorni - 3 settimane - alla data di acquisto
    $date_mod = date_create('now')->setTimestamp($utime);
    date_add($date_mod,date_interval_create_from_date_string("2 days"));
    $readyForExport['delivery_date'] = date_format($date_mod,"d/m/Y");
```

Comment: DateTime constructor can accept many date string formats. `date_create` is an alias of the DateTime constructor so `date_create(strtotime('2018-02-01'))` will return false. Example: https://3v4l.org/XMBpL and  [PHP Manual Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the bug.

Comment: Using `@` in the `DateTime` constructor or `modify` method for unix timestamps will ignore the default timezone and the resulting dates varies between different PHP versions.Example: https://3v4l.org/Y9ifd and  [PHP Manual Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-parameters)

Comment: Better example of the issue I am referring to https://3v4l.org/fSAV2, note the Date is now the 21st instead of the specified 20th.

Comment: Well I am using method `$d1 = date_create('@' . $time);` which is the same for both php versions shown in 3v4l.org but I must admit defeat regarding the time zone.

Comment: Would method 3 be sufficient? `$date_mod = date_create('now')->setTimestamp($utime);`

Comment: Yes, using `setTimestamp` when manipulating unix timestamps is the prefered method: Example https://3v4l.org/Q6jUI

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were experiencing is related to 
`strtotime($readyForExport['date_add'])` only supporting an ["English date format"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-description) and returning `false`. The result of which can be [seen in this example](https://3v4l.org/5A8Lf).

```
#locale formatted
var_dump(strtotime('30/12/2015')); //bool(false)

#English formatted
var_dump(strtotime('12/30/2015')); //int(1451430000)
```

To provide a more comprehensive solution, using the the `d/m/Y`format *`(01/01/1979)`* from the dates as displayed in the image. As I noticed some dates in the image are formatted as `30/11/-0001`, which would also fail `new \DateTime` and throw an Exception as stated in my comment.

This solution will validate the `date_add` value supplied is using the desired format.
Then use the validated date to add two days and set the desired format for the `delivery_date`.

Example `30/12/2015`: https://3v4l.org/RZ8VZ

```
$dateFormat = 'd/m/Y';
if (!empty($readyForExport['date_add']) && 
    $dateAdd = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $readyForExport['date_add'])) 
{
    $dateMod = $dateAdd->modify('+2 days');
    $readyForExport['delivery_date'] = $dateMod->format($dateFormat);
}
var_dump($readyForExport);
var_dump($dateAdd->format($dateFormat));
var_dump($dateMod->format($dateFormat));
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["date_add"]=>
  string(10) "30/12/2015"
  ["delivery_date"]=>
  string(10) "01/01/2016"
}
string(10) "30/12/2015"
string(10) "01/01/2016"
```

Invalid Date Example `30/11/-0001`: https://3v4l.org/3A8LI

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["date_add"]=>
  string(11) "30/11/-0001"
  ["delivery_date"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Many thanks now I understand and it's usefull for others in the future